# Response header has duplicated values

Tags: java, kotlin, http-headers, quarkus, resteasy

I have two simple microservices through which the download file flows, but for some unknown reason some header values are duplicated.

First service where is Response build:

```
@POST
@Path(PRINT_PREVIEW)
fun print(@Valid printRequest: PrintRequest): Response {

    // printPreview is Pair<String, ByteArrayInputStream>
    val printPreview = printService.printPreview(printRequest)

    return Response.ok(printPreview.second)
        .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=${printPreview.first}")
        .type("application/pdf")
        .build()
}
```

And in the second microservice the response is just reused:

CLIENT interface:

```
@POST
@Path(PRINT_PREVIEW)
fun printPreview(request: PrintRequest): Response
```

CONTROLLER:

```
@POST
@Path(PRINT_PREVIEW)
fun printPreview(@Valid request: NewAdhocContractRequest): Response {
    log.info("printPreview: request=$request")
    return contractService.printPreview(request)
}
```

And as a result, the response header contains duplicate values:
[image]

However, when I println what header the Response has, it looks ok, no duplicates.

```
println(printPreview.headers)
```

[Content-Disposition=attachment; filename=Test_KNZ_1BB__modelace_2022722_104020.pdf,Content-Type=application/pdf,transfer-encoding=chunked]

Any idea how to avoid it? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried not setting it at all and let the framework set it

Comment: the framework doesn't know what file name to set or what do you mean?